# Limits of two variables function

Tags: real-analysis

if we have a function for example $f(x,y) = \frac{x-1+y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$ and we want to evaluate a limit in (1,0) in other words $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)}$.I know that to show that limit doesn't exist in some point we need to take 2 different paths, and get two different values of limit in this point. Therefore can we take the path x = 0 to check  the limit in point (1,0)? I think, that no because taking x = 0 means that we are checking the limit in (0,0), am i right? So can i take x = 1?

Comment: The point $(1,0)$ does not belong to the line $x=0$, and therefore, no, you cannot use this line in order to determine the limit.

Comment: what if i would like to express x with y. Then i would have to take x = y +1 and i couldn't take x = y as y approach to 0, am i right?

Comment: That makes no sense *at all*. If $x=y+1$, then $x$ will *never* be equal to $y$.

Comment: but y approach to 0 so, the limit of y + 1 will be 1 and this equal lijmit point

Comment: I misread your previous comment; it seemed to me that you wrote that you could take $x=y+1$ *and* $x=y$. Yes, the line $x=y+1$ is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought process is correct, you just need to work on the details:

Let $(x,y)$ be a point in $\mathbb R^2$ and suppose that $(x,y)\to(1,0)$. The two "paths" that you speak of can be thought of as going along the line $y=0$ or the vertical line $x=1$ and how do you do that?

approaching from the line $y=0$ is the same as taking the limit as $\delta \to 0$ at $(1,\delta)$. That way, we fix the $x$ coordinate and let $(1,\delta)$ be a point in the line $y=0$ approaching the point $(1,0)$.

In the same way, if you want to do this along the line $x=1$, you take the limit as $\delta \to 0$ at $(1+\delta,0)$ or equivalently, the limit as $\delta\to 1$ at $(\delta,0)$